# Download stops due to missing data matlab

Tags: matlab, web, download

I am using `websave` function of MATLAB to download data from a website. The data is arranged by date. I have put the date in a loop to run the code for a certain period of time. However, on some dates, there is no data available. For those dates, the program halts and give 'internal error'.

I want to know how can I download data without interruptions even if there is missing data on some dates avoiding this internal error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, that sounds like a very poorly designed API if you're getting internal errors for an empty query result. Maybe there is a better way to make the call that you need? If you show some more code maybe we can help you.

That being said, you can use the [`try`/`catch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) construct to surround the call to `websave`, that way if it throws an error, it will not interrupt the flow of your program.

```
for k = date_range
    try
        websave(filename, url);
    catch
        % There was some error
        disp('Skipping this one!')
    end
end
```